# Textarea Not Sending Value through Form

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, textarea

So I have a form in my view..

```
  form_for(ActivityComment.new, remote: true, url: "/activity_comments/create", class: "col-md-6") do |f|
    f.hidden_field :klass_name, value: activity.klass
    f.hidden_field :klass_id, value: activity.id
    f.text_area :comment, class: "form-control"
    f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-success"
  end
```

The html is printed out as...

```
<form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/activity_comments/create" class="new_activity_comment" data-remote="true" id="new_activity_comment" method="post">
  <div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
  </div>
  <input id="activity_comment_klass_name" name="activity_comment[klass_name]" type="hidden" value="Friend">
  <input id="activity_comment_klass_id" name="activity_comment[klass_id]" type="hidden" value="3">
  <textarea class="form-control" id="activity_comment_comment" name="activity_comment[comment]"></textarea>
  <input class="btn btn-success" name="commit" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

However the params I receive in the controller is...

```
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "activity_comment"=>{"klass_name"=>"Friend", "klass_id"=>"3", "comment"=>""}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

The activity comment model

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: activity_comments
#
#  id         :integer          not null, primary key
#  user_id    :integer
#  klass_name :string(255)
#  klass_id   :integer
#  comment    :text
#  created_at :datetime
#  updated_at :datetime

class ActivityComment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

The `comment` attribute is returning empty no matter what. I'm to believe that it has something to do with the textarea as using a plain input field made it work. What's wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: When you inspect the HTTP request before it hits the controller, how is it being sent?

Comment: I believe a POST request. But I need to double check on that.

Comment: Check if the request contains the form data from your textarea when it's being sent to your controller. In Chrome, you can check in the developer tools under Network tab, by clicking on the POST request and looking for Form data. Viewing the raw request might help more.

Comment: Looks like this: http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/6604937/Screenshots/z499xibm5asd.png

Comment: It is a POST request. It looks like the comment is still not being passed through. It is the only field that has no value.

Comment: have you tried explicitly setting a default value?   f.text_area :comment, class: "form-control", value: "default text"

Comment: Yes, it doesn't do anything different.

Comment: Can you post the code of your model as well

Comment: What is the output of `$('#new_activity_comment').serializeArray()` in the browser console? Does it have the textarea value as a last object?

Comment: Do you have any gem installed that could impact the value of the Text areas? Something like a WYSIWYG (code Editor) or a Javascript library?

Comment: @MrYoshiji No gem that I can think of.

Comment: What `activity_comment.update_attributes(comment: 'foo')` returns?

Comment: @antiqe It returns true. I don't think the issue is with saving it, I've already determined that the Rails server DOES NOT receive the comment parameter.

Comment: What version of jQuery are you running? What is the output of `$('#new_activity_comment').serializeArray()`, does it have your textarea data in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll be hard to come up with a solution since this seems to be a very located problem. So here are just some steps I'd recommend to take in order to nail it down, rather than a shorthand solution:

1. Check the output of `$('#new_activity_comment').serializeArray()` in the browser console when you are on the actual page with the form in it.

   This is what the js handling the `data-remote="true"` forms in `jquery-rails` does to serialize your form data before it sends it to the server.

   The resulting Javascript `Array` should have an object with name `"activity_comment[comment]"` and value `"Your comment"` in it.

   If it does not, your error comes from somewhere in your Javascript or HTML. Where is difficult to say unless you post the JS sources, your `HTML Doctype` etc.

   **EDIT:** 1.5. Remove the `"form-control"` class from the textarea and see if it solves your problem. If it does not, try to rip out all the JS coming from Bootstrap and check if your forms are doing ok now. If they are, the problem lies with Bootstrap.
2. Check your Networks tab in the developer tools when you send the request: Your headers should have `FormData` in them and there you should see `activity_comment[comment]` and your textarea value. If you don't, chances are you're operating on a broken build of jQuery or something with your browser is wrong / you're using a broken build of that, though that is very very unlikely unless you're on some Canary / Alpha Build channel for Chromium or something else.
3. If your Javascript and Browser is sending the form ok and you still get no textarea value in your rails controller, log the contents of the raw rack parameters like that to your rails log:

   ```
   Rails.logger.info '###' #makes it easier to find your params
   Rails.logger.info URI.decode(request.env["rack.request.form_vars"])
   ```

   Now, if `Rack` has the right form value, but rails does not, there are 2 possibilities:

   1. Either there is something messed up in your app with strong parameters, meaning you will have to check for any `params.require` or `params.permit` in your `ActivityCommentsController` or any `Controller` in its `ancestors`
   2. There's a bug somewhere in the `Rails` `Rack`/`ActionController` interface, though that is also highly unlikely. Try to update rails to the latest patch version in that case or try to search for `ActionController` bugs in the `Rails` issues on github.

Comment: thanks for a comphrensive post. Here are the results. The form data is shown in the headers, and I do see `activity_comment[comment]` however it's value is blank. I removed the bootstrap code and any other 3rd party libraries however the error still persists. As for the the jQuery version, I have `1.10.2`. Finally, I've tested this on Chrome on Mac and Chromium on Ubuntu.

Comment: @jason328 Ok, and what's the output of `$('#new_activity_comment').serializeArray()` - does it have your textarea data in it?

Comment: I actually fixed it. serializeArray returned the appropriate information. The problem was my js was altering the text area before submission. Thanks for the in-depth help.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you understand what `form_for remote :true` does? It turns your form into an ajax loader. So if that's acting up, then some javascript is to blame. Look at your javascript console in chrome for clues.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of what remote true does. I've already viewed my javascript console and it tells me the data was sent, all except for the text area. As I mentioned in my question, changing text area to a text field fixes the problem, but I need it to be a text area.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try adding `attr_accessable :comment` to your model